# String to timestamp (redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a date field in string format and I want to turn it into a timestamp, but this happens:

String: "24/12/2021 11:12:25"

Using: to_timestamp (date,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as date

Result: "2021-12-24 11:12:25.000 -0300"

Answer (score 0):

So I think there is something going on not in your description.  I can run the below code and get a reasonable answer.

```
create table foo as select '15/04/2022 08:04:37'::varchar(20) as dt;

select to_timestamp(dt,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from foo;
```

It produces -

> 2022-04-15 08:04:37+00

Can you show the error you are seeing with simple code like this?  If not can you provide some more information about your exact query, table definition, etc.?

Comment: I want: "2022-04-15 08:04:37" just

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html) function converts string to [TIMESTAMPTZ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Datetime_types.html#r_Datetime_types-timestamptz). This type is an alias of TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. All you have to do is to drop time zone part using a cast to TIMESTAMP type:

```
select cast(to_timestamp ('24/12/2021 11:12:25','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp)
```

or in shorter form:

```
select to_timestamp ('24/12/2021 11:12:25','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp
```

Both will return `2021-12-24 11:12:25`